# Error in pl/sql code while executing procedure Error(9,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "VAR"

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

This code:

```
set serveroutput on;  
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TAX_COST_SP(  
      p_state  IN BB_TAX.STATE%TYPE,  
      p_subtotal IN BB_TAX.TAXRATE%TYPE,  
      p_tax_amount OUT BB_TAX.TAXRATE%TYPE)  
    IS  
    BEGIN  
     SELECT TAXRATE*p_subtotal INTO p_tax_amount FROM BB_TAX WHERE  STATE='p_state';
    END TAX_COST_SP;  
    var G_TAX NUMBER;  
    EXECUTE TAX_COST_SP('VA',100,:G_TAX);  
    dbms_output.put_line(g_tax);]
```

produces the following error:

> Error in pl/sql code while executing procedure Error(9,1): PLS-00103:
>   Encountered the symbol “VAR”

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work for you

```
DECLARE
var G_TAX NUMBER;  
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TAX_COST_SP(  
  p_state  IN BB_TAX.STATE%TYPE,  
  p_subtotal IN BB_TAX.TAXRATE%TYPE,  
  p_tax_amount OUT BB_TAX.TAXRATE%TYPE)  
 IS  
 BEGIN  
 SELECT TAXRATE*p_subtotal INTO p_tax_amount FROM BB_TAX WHERE  
 STATE='p_state';
 END TAX_COST_SP;  

 BEGIN
 EXECUTE TAX_COST_SP('VA',100,:G_TAX);  
 dbms_output.put_line(g_tax);
 END;
```

Answer (score 0):

These solutions suffer from structural issues. To begin with "Create or Replace *StoredProcedureType*.... End" stands on it's own and cannot be in a plsql block, which  "Declare" opens. (You can put it in a block by enclosing entirely within ticks (') thus a string and then using execute immediate.) It is the code equivalent of DDL "Create table". So it needs to come outside the declare or better another session or at least a separate buffer (assuming you're using sqlplus). Secondly, "var" and "execute" are slqplus commands not plsql statements; so they also do not go in a plsql block. Within a block you do not need to tell plsql you are defining a variable; just define it. Neither do you use EXECUTE to invoke a procedure; just use it's name and supply the parameters. When in sqlplus you use single slash (/) to tell sqlplus to run the proceeding. So your single sqlplus buffer becomes:

```
 Create Or Replace Procedure tax_cost_sp(  
     p_state  in bb_tax.state%type,  
     p_subtotal in bb_tax.taxrate%type,  
     p_tax_amount out bb_tax.taxrate%type)  
 is  
 begin  
     select taxrate*p_subtotal 
       into p_tax_amount 
       from bb_tax 
      where state='p_state';
 end tax_cost_sp;  
/
-- BETTER to start new session or buffer here
declare
  g_tax number; 
begin
    tax_cost_sp('VA',100,g_tax);  
    dbms_output.put_line(g_tax);
 end;
/
```

Now within the procedure you have a critical error. The WHERE clause tells Oracle retrieve the for the state containing the literal 'p_state' not the contents of the parameter p_state. Unless the table contains a STATE column with value 'p_state' you'll get a NO_DATA_FOUND exception. Your WHERE clause should read:

```
 where state=p_state;
```

Finally since you are calculating a single value consider a Function instead of a procedure. You could then use it in SQL as below (which you cannot do with a procedure).

```
Select tax_cost_sp('VA',100) from dual;
```